# Sending 2 dimensional array through formData using jQuery ajax to python flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, arrays, ajax

I have a form which I need to add some variables to before sending it to the server which is python flask.
I used the following code to send the form which works fine except when sending 2 dimensional array it will treat it as 1 dimensional in flask

javascript:

```
form = document.getElementById('calculator-form');
fdata = new FormData(form);
fdata.append('readings', plotData.readings);
$.ajax({
    url: "some/url/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: fdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});
```

so if `plotData.readings=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`
I receive it in flask `1,2,3,4,5,6` and I don't always know the size of the array to reshape it from flask, is there a way to send so that the backend see it as 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Try `fdata.append('readings', JSON.stringify(plotData.readings));` for sending, then you'll have to decode JSON, I'm not familiar with Python, but I'm sure there is a simple way to do it, JSON is a very popular format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought there was a straight forward way without having to convert to json and converting back to list in python but this looks good for my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `plotData.readings` as stringified JSON with `JSON.stringify(plotData.readings)` in Javascript. Then, in your Python app:

```
import json

json.loads(request.POST["readings"], encoding="utf-8") # Just an example
```